# SQL: Filter data by datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a massive table I'm trying to thin out in MS SQL Server Management Studio. Currently there is a row for every 5 seconds of data. I want to shrink the table and only save 1 row for every 30 minutes.

For example, instead of having thousands of rows at

```
    Timestamp            A   B   C
    2015-01-01 00:00:00  1   5   6
    2015-01-01 00:00:05  5   7   1
    2015-01-01 00:00:10  2   2   3
    2015-01-01 00:00:15  2   1   0
    ......
    2015-04-10 13:55:55  4   5   6
    2015-04-10 13:56:00  6   4   2
```

I want to thin it out so I only have

```
    Timestamp            A   B   C
    2015-01-01 00:00:00  1   5   6
    2015-01-01 00:30:00  2   5   7
    2015-01-01 01:00:00  1   7   6
    ......
    2015-04-10 13:30:00  4   5   6
    2015-04-10 14:00:00  6   4   2
```

Thank you!

Comment: To clarify, do you want it to snapshot every 30 seconds, or should the rows contain all of the data since the previous 30 seconds?  That is, do you want to delete all the rows where the timestamp is not a 30-second-interval, or do you want to sum your data (I'm guessing counts) for each interval?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I just want a snapshot every 30 minutes so the rest of the data isn't needed and can be deleted.

Comment: Will the last digit (on the seconds) always be a 0 or 5 or is it possible to have data that is 3 seconds after the hour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your sample data, you could do:

```
select t.*
from table t
where datepart(minute, timestamp) in (0, 30) and
      datepart(second, timestamp) = 0;
```

Comment: If the task is to thin out the table, then `delete from t where not (datepart(second, timestamp) in (0, 30) and datepart(second, timestamp) = 0);`

Comment: Every good delete statement should start off as a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

`delete from [massive Table] where datepart(mi,timestamp) not in (0,30)`

will delete all rows that don't match your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If your times don't always and in 0 or 5, you could try this instead.

```
Delete
From    YourTable
Where   DateDiff(Second, '20000101', TimeStamp) % 1800 > 4
```

This works by calculating the number of seconds that have expired since Jan 1, 2000.  The mod operator is used to calculate the intervals you want to keep.  There are 1800 seconds in 30 minutes.  Therefore, anything with seconds greater than 4 should be removed.  Basically, instead of thinking about time in terms of hours, minutes and seconds, we are thinking about the time in terms of 1800 second intervals, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting one row from a group of rows, it is not always a good idea to write code that relies on assumptions that may not be true. For example, when looking for the first entry on the hour and on the half-hour, is it guaranteed that there will always be an entry with the time stamp "hh-00-00" and "hh-30-00"? Your sample data shows that but does that accurately represent your actual data in that way?

What you may want to say is that you want to keep the "first entry after each hour and half-hour boundary." That way, you know you will have one entry for each half-hour interval, even if the first entry came in at, say, two seconds after the hour or half-hour.

So the first step is to separate the date into half-hour groups. The best way I've found to do that is

```
Convert( SmallDatetime, Floor( Cast( Timestamp AS float ) * 48.0 ) / 48.0 )
```

Tack that on the end of a query list and see if the correct time (rounded down to exactly on the hour or exactly on the half-hour). Pay particular attention to times that are very close to (before and after) the boundary.

Using that, it's easy to generate a list of the times that are the first to occur within each half-hour increment. You don't have to worry that each increment has an entry that matches the half-hour boundary to the second. Join on that and you get a complete list of rows to keep. Delete all the rest.

```
with
Halfs( HalfHour )as(
    select  Min( Timestamp )
    from    TData
    group by Convert( SmallDatetime, Floor( Cast( Timestamp AS float ) * 48.0 ) / 48.0 )
)
select  t.*
from    TData t
join    Halfs h
    on  h.HalfHour = t.TimeStamp;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/65a5c/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might help:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Position](
[PositionId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY,
[Latitude] [float] NOT NULL,
[Longitude] [float] NOT NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[DeviceId] [int] NOT NULL
)

insert into Position Values
(51.46,-2.58,'2022-01-04 08:05:00',1),
(51.41,-2.53,'2022-01-04 08:25:00',1),
(51.39,-2.48,'2022-01-04 08:45:00',1),
(51.39,-2.45,'2022-01-04 08:50:00',1),
(51.38,-2.37,'2022-01-04 09:10:00',1),
(51.41,-2.52,'2022-01-04 09:30:00',1),
(51.44,-2.56,'2022-01-04 09:50:00',1),
(51.45,-2.57,'2022-01-04 10:20:00',1),
(51.46,-2.58,'2022-01-04 11:40:00',1)

Declare @IntervalHours int = 1
Declare @Start Datetime = '2022-01-04 07:00'
Declare @End Datetime = '2022-01-04 12:00'
Declare @DeviceId int = 1

SELECT PositionId, [Date], RoundedDate, Latitude, Longitude, DeviceId
FROM (SELECT 
        PositionId, 
        Latitude, 
        Longitude,
        [Date],
        DATEADD(hour, DATEDIFF(hour, 0, [Date]), 0) AS RoundedDate, 
        DeviceId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (DATEDIFF(hour, 0, [Date])/@IntervalHours) ORDER BY [Date] ASC) AS row_index
    From Position
    WHERE Date BETWEEN @Start AND @End and DeviceId = @DeviceId
    GROUP BY [Date], PositionId, Latitude,Longitude,DeviceId
    ) as grouped
where grouped.row_index = 1
```